# NodeJs - How to get key value from mongoose output

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using below function to query a mongoose model and it gives output as

[{"count":10000}].I would like to know how to i retrieve the value of count from json returned by mongoose, so that i can use it for performing certain arithmetic operations.

```
 module.exports.getNext = function (field, model) {

    mongoose.model(collection, identityCounterSchema).find({ 'field': field, 'model': model }, { "count": 1, "_id": 0 }, function (err, result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
    console.log(jsonObj.count)
    return (jsonObj.count);
});
}
```

jsonObj.count in the above code snippet is returning undefined.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code, but `stringify` then `parse` is redundant ? You can use result as normal JS object !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` in an array, you need to use `result[0].count` to get count.
And you don't need parse `result` to string and after that back to object, it's already an object.

Also if you want to get only one document, you should use `model.findOne()` function:

```
mongoose.model(collection, identityCounterSchema)
  .findOne({ field, model })
  .then(obj => {
    console.log(obj);
    return (obj.count);
  })
  .catch(err => /* process error*/);
```